# Send user defined error message to React JS from responseEntity

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

I have a superagent call to my java code. In that Java Controller - I am throwing user defined exception message as below.

In service :

```
if (user_id == null){
   throw new Exception("User ID is missing!!!");
}
```

In controller:

```
Map<String, String> resp = new HashMap<String,String>();
   try{
     String returnValue= myserviceobj.myservicemethod;
   }catch(Exception e){
     resp.put("status","ERROR");
     resp.put("message",e.getMessage());
     return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>>(resp, HttpStatus.Bad_Response);
}
```

In React Js I am using superagent to make service call. I am not sure how to access that user defined exception message in UI.

Here is what I do in JS:

```
webservice(data, actionName, (error,resp){
   if(error){
     //call alert and send the user defined message.
   }
})
```

Comment: You mean you wish to add an alert component or something like a service handler ?

Comment: In JS side I have to display that message in alert

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/alert ?

Anyway i would use Redux to check the state of my app and dispatch an alert action.

Maybe this is what your looking for : https://alexanderpaterson.com/posts/showing-and-dismissing-alerts-in-a-react-application

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I am actually looking for a way to access it. Sorry that I mentioned as "display the message" instead of accessing